# What does it mean if X → Y → Z is a markov chain, it mplies that Z → Y → X. Some-times written X ↔ Y ↔ Z

Tags: random-variable, markov-process, information-theory

In the book *Elements of information theory (Cover, Thomas) 2nd ed. Page 34*

On Markov Chain it says:

```
X → Y → Z implies that Z → Y → X. 
Thus, the condition is some-times written X ↔ Y ↔ Z.
```

I just don't get this.

1. Is this property has any name?
2. What does it exactly mean? Is it mean that this is always the case for any markov chain?
3. **This might seem silly!** Let us consider a random variable $X \in [-10,10]$, $Y=X^2$, and $Z=\sqrt{Y}$. Can we say that $X \rightarrow X^2 \rightarrow \sqrt{X^2}$  is a markov chain? If `Yes` then does this means that  $\sqrt{X^2} \rightarrow X^2 \rightarrow X$ is also a markov chain? If `Yes` then how the second chain can recover X?

I appreciate any intuitive example that elaborates this property.

Answer (score 3):

It is right.

Let $X\rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z$ be a Markov chain.

The joint probability $p(x,y,z)$ can be factorized thanks the Markovian property:

$$
p(x, y, z) = p(x)p(y|x)p(z|y)
$$

At the same time, you have (using Bayes theorem):

$$
p(z|y) = \frac{p(y|z)p(z)}{p(y)}\\
p(y|x) = \frac{p(x|y)p(y)}{p(x)}
$$

which gives:

$$
p(x,y,z)=p(x)\frac{p(x|y)p(y)}{p(x)}\frac{p(y|z)p(z)}{p(y)}=p(x|y)p(y|z)p(z)
$$

which can be represented as $Z\rightarrow Y \rightarrow X$.

This is an important property extensively used in Bayesian networks.